# Taxonomy Alphabetical Sorting - Nested or Multi-Level Terms

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I have a problem with the taxonomy list. Currently my website's taxonomy is unsorted, and I want to do an alphabetical sort. It is also a multi-level nested list (3 levels). I heard that using 'Reset to alphabetical' button would sort the list as a whole, and not sorting it within the sub-levels. Is there a way to address that? Currently I'm doing a drag-and-drop sort manually, but there are tons of terms and I'd appreciate any help with that! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may reset the list to alphabetical without losing your hierarchy. While the terms will be sorted alphabetically, those terms that have a parent item will keep that parent item, and so naturally will continue to be displayed under that parent in the hierarchy.

The reset button is found at the bottom of the list terms page in Drupal 7

Answer (score 0):

Reset to Alphabetical button is worked not only on parent terms but also on child terms as well. So, if you have a term hierarchy as:

```
Term 1
 - My term 3
 - My term 2
 - My term 1
    - My term 32
    - My term 22
Term
```

After Reset to Alphabetical:

```
Term 
Term 1
 - My term 1
    - My term 22
    - My term 32
 - My term 2
 - My term 3
```

Do take a backup of your DB before clicking that button.